# PBSpro: $PBS_NODEFILE variable empty

Tags: hpc, pbs

For some reason, my $PBS_NODEFILE is empty, even when requesting multiple nodes / hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be dependent on having mpiprocs set:

`#PBS -l select=60:ncpus=4:mpiprocs=0`  - nodefile empty.

`#PBS -l select=60:ncpus=4:mpiprocs=1`  - nodefile contains list of nodes.